# How to export multiple csv files from postgresql for loop query?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have got 100 state codes. I need to use them in a query like this:

```
select *
from public.clients
where state = '01'
```

and get 100 different .csv files. I haven't got superuser rights, so if I got it right I can only do it with `\copy` in psql command line. But I can't understand how to use it properly.

I tried to make it like this:

```
DO
$do$
declare
    i   text;
    arr text[] := array(
                    select distinct state
                    from public.clients c 
                    where state is not null
                    order by state);
BEGIN
   FOREACH i IN ARRAY arr
   LOOP
        EXECUTE format($x$\COPY (
   SELECT *
   FROM   public.clients c 
   WHERE  c."state" = %1$s)
   TO 'G:\Desktop\states\.%1$s.out.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER$x$, i);
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

But I got `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"` and I think it's not the last error because I'm not sure in this `WHERE  c."state" = %1$s` and this `TO 'G:\Desktop\states\.%1$s.out.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER$x$, i);`

Comment: I don't test your code, I think you must replace \ with \\

Comment: You're right about `COPY TO file` needing superuser rights and the need for `\copy`. The weird thing is that your code is for `COPY TO file` even though you can't use it.

Comment: @DanielVérité I think his real code actually is using `\COPY`, otherwise we wouldn't be getting that error message.

Comment: Yes, I was using '\copy', not just 'copy'

Answer (score 0):

DO sends it program to the server to run.  Since `\copy` is a `psql` metacommand, the server won't know how to run it.  So you can't do it this way.

You also can't use the `\gexec` metacommand, as that can only be used to run SQL commands, not other metacommands.

So you can write a script (say, perl or python, or bash) to print out a series of `\copy...` and then pipe that into `psql`, or send it to a file and execute `psql -f file.sql`